# How to change model data via plugin

Tags: magento2, php, model, plugin

How to make a plugin for a model and turn one of its fields into a different value.

For example, in the documentation, they make an after plugin for the model and return a different value.

```
    public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        return '|' . $result . '|';
    }
```

How to do the same only through around?

My modules do not have get name methods and the like. I have a standard Model, I load it through Factory in my class and create a method to get all data from modules using:

```
    public function getAllMyData()
    {
        return $this->friendFactory->create()->getCollection();
    }
```

and use plugin

```
    public function aroundGetAllMyData(\My\Module\ViewModel\MyViewOnModel $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        return $subject;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **No need for a plugin to modify your model data, if you own the model**

In your Model Class, lets assume

`\Vendor\Module\Model\Friend`

You have a field in the collection `nickname` and you want to `change the nickname to some text or append some text to the existing nick name, when you load and retrieve the collection`

So, just throw a getter method `getNickname`

```
public function getNickname() {
    return ' My Besty';
}
```

In case if you want to append some thing to the existing data then you can use this,

```
public function getNickname() {
    return parent::getNickname() . ' My Besty';
}
```

If you retrieve your collection, and `getNickname()` you can find the changed or appended string.

BTW you can also add a different method like `getNicknameWithBesty` and retrieve the data.

```
public function getNicknameWithBesty() {
    return parent::getNickname() . ' My Besty';
}
```